# Options from mysql

Tags: php

I have this code:

```html
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">.....................:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="vip">

    <?php
        $conn = new mysqli(".............................");
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM servers WHERE owner_id = ?";
        $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $result->bind_param('s', getID($_SESSION["prihlaseni"]));
        $result->execute();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          //I have in database 3 rows of servers
          //But, in options is 0 options
          ?> <option value="test">dsa</option> <?php

        }   
    ?>

    </select>
  </div>
```

I have 3 rows of servers in database, but 0 options are displayed.

But the code is not working, why?

Comment: What value does `getID($_SESSION["prihlaseni"])` return?

Comment: ID of user (example : DomiHrajeCZ)

Comment: using a prepared statement means you need to access the recordset differently to when using a standard `query`. What fields are you using to populate the `select` menu?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the fields actually used in the population of the `select` menu I guessed at `id` and `server` ~ no point returning all fields if only a couple or more are required!

As you are using a prepared statement you can't iterate through the recordset as you would for a normal `$con->query( $sql );` type operation  -instead you need to do something like the following.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">.....................:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="vip">
    <?php

        $conn = new mysqli(".............................");
        if( !$conn->connect_error ){

            /* select the fields used to build the menu */
            $sql = 'select `id`,`server` from `servers` where `owner_id` = ?';
            $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bind_param('s', getID($_SESSION["prihlaseni"]));

            $result=$stmt->execute();
            if( $result ){

                $stmt->store_result();
                $stmt->bind_result( $id, $server );

                while( $stmt->fetch() ){
                    printf( '<option value="%s">%s', $id, $server );
                }
            }           
        }
    ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: any errors to report? Did you edit the sql appropriately to select correct column names?

Comment: [Sun Dec 22 16:36:23.224399 2019] [php7:error] [pid 15736:tid 1896] [client ::1:64847] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dashboard\\admin\\panel.php:76\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dashboard\\admin\\panel.php on line 76

Comment: I repeat: did you edit the sql to reflect the actual columns before running this? That error message suggests that you did not because the database is reporting that sql is not valid.